# Stack Overflow link expander in Google Search

Tags: script, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, stackoverflow

This userscript detects links to Stack Overflow when you Google something and shows the accepted/most-voted answer directly in the search page!

From:

[image: Before]

To:

[image: After]

---

To install, you'll need a userscript manager such as Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey.

[Install script from here](https://gist.github.com/shu8/4d433dbb7729416d7555785994834f6e/raw/fde5a790e9f4a79d363247b59a6cfc13316f5013/soLinkExpander.user.js), or [view the source here](https://gist.github.com/shu8/4d433dbb7729416d7555785994834f6e)

---

I aim to make it look a bit better when I get a bit more time, and fix a few bugs. Please post bugs as answers here :)